# What's a word for: "just to feel good about yourself"?

Tags: synonyms

For example: You want approval and people to think you're smart, just to feel good about yourself.

Comment: Are you talking about self esteem?

Comment: Self assurance that's closer to arrogance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say someone is "looking for approval" already suggests a lack of self-confidence, which might or might not lead to arrogance, but which in any case focuses on the person's state of mind rather than an idea or opinion. "Validation" is often used to suggest someone's need for support, but it does not imply arrogance without additional context, as in 'You want approval and people to think you're smart, to "validate" or "justify" your sense of self-importance.'

Comment: Self-importance. That's the word I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for ***[reassured](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reassured)***:

> - (of a person) feeling less worried about something, usually after receiving help or advice.

(Collins)

Comment: Yes, I wanted but I wanted something closer to self assurance but with a little bit of delusion or arrogance...?

Comment: Yes, I wanted assurance*

Answer (score 0):

**need for recognition**

> Recognition and appreciation are fundamental human needs: we want to
>   know that our effort is valued and appreciated by others.

Answer (score 0):

The need to be **comforted** maybe?

> comfort
>
> : improve the mood of or restore a sense of well-being to:
>
> [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/comfort)